# showing error during debugging

Tags: android, database-connection, android-contentresolver

I have a method call in onReceive method.

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        SaveCallLog();
}
public boolean SaveCallLog() 
    {
        info = new TelephonyInfo();
        imei1 = info.getImeiSIM1();

        imei2 = "";
        if (info.isDualSIM()) {
            imei2 = info.getImeiSIM2();
        }

        Uri uri = Uri.parse("content://call_log/calls");
        ContentResolver contentResolver = mContext.getContentResolver();

        // here change where condition to get only those call logs those are not sent before
        Cursor cursor = contentResolver.query(uri, null, null, null, "date DESC");
        {
            if (cursor != null && cursor.getCount() > 0) 
            {
                while (cursor.moveToNext()) 
                {
                    phNumber = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.NUMBER));
                    callType = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.TYPE));
                    callDate = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.DATE));
                    callDuration = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.DURATION));

                    dir = null;
                    int dircode = Integer.parseInt(callType);
                    switch (dircode)  
                    {
                        case CallLog.Calls.OUTGOING_TYPE:
                            dir = "OUTGOING";
                            break;
                        case CallLog.Calls.INCOMING_TYPE:
                            dir = "INCOMING";
                            break;
                        case CallLog.Calls.MISSED_TYPE:
                            dir = "MISSED";
                            break;
                        default:
                            dir = "REJECTED";
                    }
                    // here save the call log in your database to send them later
                    //String QS = "call&ImeiNo=" + "imei1" + "&ph=" + phNumber + "&duration=" + callDuration + "&date=" + callDate + "&cType=" + dir + "";
                 }



    cursor.close();
            Log.e("cursor", "here it is");

        }
        return true;    
    }
```

---->While Debugging as I reached to
`ContentResolver contentResolver = mContext.getContentResolver();`
It swaps me out from this page.

I have tried too much to resolve these issues But can't understand the problem of occurring these problems

Comment: **mContext** initialized???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`mContext` is not initialized..SO it giving you `NullPointerException`.

change your code like this..

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    mContext=context;
    SaveCallLog();
}
```

add this permission..in manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALL_LOG"/>
```

Based on OP requirement..

change your code like this and try..

```
// here change where condition to get only those call logs those are not
    // sent before
    Cursor cursor = contentResolver.query(uri, null, null, null,
            "date DESC");

    try {
        if (cursor != null) {
            if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                do {
                    phNumber = cursor.getString(cursor
                            .getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.NUMBER));
                    callType = cursor.getString(cursor
                            .getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.TYPE));
                    callDate = cursor.getString(cursor
                            .getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.DATE));
                    callDuration = cursor.getString(cursor
                            .getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.DURATION));

                    dir = null;
                    int dircode = Integer.parseInt(callType);
                    switch (dircode) {
                    case CallLog.Calls.OUTGOING_TYPE:
                        dir = "OUTGOING";
                        break;
                    case CallLog.Calls.INCOMING_TYPE:
                        dir = "INCOMING";
                        break;
                    case CallLog.Calls.MISSED_TYPE:
                        dir = "MISSED";
                        break;
                    default:
                        dir = "REJECTED";
                    }
                } while (cursor.moveToNext());
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
    }
```

Comment: Thanks,that issue is solved, But Now it stops from if statement

Comment: @Anjali is any solution found??

Comment: @Anjali, if your first issue is solved by this answer then honestly you should first accept the answer and then go ahead.

Comment: 12-31 04:50:53.607: E/SoundPool(284): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg

Comment: it unexpectedly closes while running

Comment: @Anjali add this permission <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALL_LOG"/> in manifest file..

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44216/discussion-between-kalyan-pvs-and-anjali)